# R: Loop over table to create urls to further operation?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

So i have a table: 100 rows and 3 columns, and I would like to use R to create url strings from them, which are for further processing.

```
first rows of the Table is:
X1 X2         X3
1  text1      16
2  text2      154
etc. text etc 21
```

I would like to get formats such that from the first row 16 urls are created in the form of: baseurl+text1+1,baseurl+text1+2, etc through 16 and then continue with row 2 same process, but then 1 through 154

I imagined something like the following, but either way it is not working, am getting empty results.

```
    baseurl <- "link"
#creating a dynamic i which goes from 1 trough input at intersection rownumber k, column 3
    i<- 1 in a1[k,2]
# creating a loop on rownumber k from table a1    
    for (k in 1:nrow(a1)) {
# pasting together baseurl, contents at intersection row k, column 2
      mydata <- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,a1[k,2],i,"0"), flatten=TRUE)

    }
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Adjustment of post:

In the end I hope to create a list of urls, which I can use for further operations. The list of urls would need to look like: (I added [] for clarity of reading reasons only, so they must not appear in the final result...)

```
[base_url][text1][1]
[base_url][text1][2]
.
.
.
[base_url][text1][16]
[base_url][text2][1]
[base_url][text2][2]
.
.
.
[base_url][text2][154]
.
.
.
.
[base_url][text100][19]
```

Comment: What would the expected result look like?

Comment: something in the order of: baseurl+text1+1, baseurl+text1+2, etc through 16. then baseurl+text2+1, baseurl+text2+2, etc through 154. and this for every row. In other words, every row should create a number of strings/urls, which are different for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked this function together, but it isn't pretty and might not be fast. It also depends on a couple outside packages.

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = 1:2, X2 = c("text1", "text2"), X3 = c(16,154))
base_url <- "https://www.your_url_here.com"

create_urls <- function(input_tbl, base_url) {
  require(magrittr)
  require(tidyr)
  require(dplyr)

  # create a list of numeric sequences from 1 to length specified in X3
  x3_sequences <- lapply(input_tbl$X3, FUN = seq)

  # combine the sequences with each row, this will create a list of lists.
  # be sure toe comment out/remove the "/" row after base_url if your url already
  # has it.
  url_lists <- mapply(FUN = paste0, 
                      base_url, 
                      "/", 
                      input_tbl$X2, 
                      "/", 
                      x3_sequences,
                      SIMPLIFY = TRUE)

  # jump through some hoops to turn the list of lists into a dataframe
  # with a single column of url values. I use the tidyr and dplyr packages here
  # for expediency. I'm sure it's possible to accomplish the same things in base,
  # but i'd rather not spend the time to figure out how.
  url_df <- url_lists %>%
    sapply(FUN = strsplit, split = " ", simplify = "vector") %>%
    lapply(FUN = as.data.frame) %>%
    lapply(FUN = tidyr::gather, key = "n", value = "url") %>% #this is necessary because the strsplt and as.data.frame functions cause each url to be placed in their own column. the gather turns these columns into unique rows
    do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
    dplyr::select(url)

  #row names are automatically added by the do.call rbind function above. They
  #only serve to clutter the dataframe, so I've removed them.              
  row.names(url_df) <- NULL

  return(url_df)
}
```

Running `create_urls(input_tbl = df, base_url = base_url)` Returns

```
                                         url
1     https://www.your_url_here.com/text1/1
2     https://www.your_url_here.com/text1/2
...
15   https://www.your_url_here.com/text1/15
16   https://www.your_url_here.com/text1/16
17    https://www.your_url_here.com/text2/1
18    https://www.your_url_here.com/text2/2
...
169 https://www.your_url_here.com/text2/153
170 https://www.your_url_here.com/text2/154
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran a test, and although it is a large chunk, it seems to work, so many thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you want the following: for each row of the data frame, create strings of the form "[base_url]/text1/n", where "n" takes the values 1 through the value of X3.

You can do this fairly easily with a call to `mapply`:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'X1 X2 X3
1 text1 16
2 text2 154', header = T)

urls <- mapply(function(x, y) {sprintf('base_url/%s/%i', x, 1:y)}, x = df$X2, y = df$X3)
```

This will return a list, each element of which contains a vector corresponding to the value of X2, with strings corresponding to the max value of X3.

Comment: sorry, when I have something in my head, and then it is difficult to explain.... a question though, is there preference of sprintf over paste0 command?

Comment: `sprintf` and `paste0` are similar for many purposes. I prefer it because it is usually faster to type and easier to read.

Comment: The equivalent would be `paste0('base_url/', x, '/', 1:y)`

Comment: thanks for your proposed solution, unfortunately, it creates only strings of mentioning text1 1x, text2 2x, text53 53x. (so strings as 'base_url'/text1/1', 'base_url/text2/1', etc... I am gonna adjust my opening post to get it somewhat clearer....